# Open a Lightning Component in a new window from partner community portal

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am looking for a way to open a lightning component in a separate window on click of a hyperlink. The hyperlink will be on another lightning component on a partner community portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can't run by themselves; they need an Application container. You could use a Lightning App or a Lightning Record Page, but you can't open it in a new window without either.